# PDO display results in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to display the results of the prepared statement into a table.

Here is the query and attempted table:

```
<?php
  $s = "SELECT username,fullname,email,userlevel FROM users";
  $sth = $dbc->prepare($s, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
  $sth->execute();

  echo "<div><table class="demoTable">";
  echo "<thead><tr>" .
       "<th>Username</th>" .
       "<th>Fullname</th>" .
       "<th>Email</th>" .
       "<th>Userlevel</th>" .
       "</tr></thead>";
  echo "<tbody>";
  
  while($Row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$Row['username']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$Row['fullname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$Row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$Row['userlevel']."</td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody>";
  }
  echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Using the above, I am getting nothing displaed onscreen.

When I use the following:

```
print_r($Row);
```

I can see the results in the array which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [username] => usr.sname [fullname] => Some Name [email] => some.name@company.com [userlevel] => 9 ) 
[1] => Array ( [username] => usr.aname [fullname] => Another Name [email] => another.name@company.com  [userlevel] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [username] => usr.fname [fullname] => Final Name [email] => final.name@company.com [userlevel] => 1 ) // a few more
```

So, the query is working properly.  I just can't get the data to display in the table.

How can I make this work?

Comment: It's probably `... while($Row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {...` (not `fetchAll`. If you want to use `fetchAll()`, you need an additional `for` loop.

Comment: As the name suggests, `fetchAll` fetches all of the data at once. Your code should've given you Undefined index notices. And your `print_r` revealed the structure. Alternatively, you could even `foreach` the executed statement directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the following works fine for me...

```
<?php
  /*
  DROP TABLE users;
  
  CREATE TABLE users(user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  ,username VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
  ,fullname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,userlevel INT NOT NULL);
  
  INSERT INTO users VALUES 
  (1,'John','John Lennon','john@apple.corp',1),
  (2,'Paul','Paul McCartney','paul@apple.corp',1),
  (3,'George','George Harrison','george@apple.corp',2),
  (4,'Ringo','Ringo Starr','ringo@apple.corp',3);
  */
  
  require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');
  $query = "SELECT username,fullname,email,userlevel FROM users";
  $data = $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
   // my connection is something like '$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);'

  echo "
  <div><table class=\"demoTable\">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Fullname</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Userlevel</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  ";

foreach($data as $row){
echo "
<tr>
 <td>{$row['username']}</td>
 <td>{$row['fullname']}</td>
 <td>{$row['email']}</td>
 <td>{$row['userlevel']}</td>
</tr>
";
}
  echo "</tbody></table></div>";
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Username Fullname        Email            Userlevel
John     John Lennon     john@apple.corp    1
Paul     Paul McCartney  paul@apple.corp    1
George   George Harrison george@apple.corp  2
Ringo    Ringo Starr     ringo@apple.corp   3
```

Comment: Using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) seems to have done the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using **fetchAll** which returns all the rows of the query not one row by one. So replace your while loop with this code and I think it  should work.

```
   <?php
   $s = "SELECT username,fullname,email,userlevel FROM users";
   $sth = $dbc->prepare($s, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
   $sth->execute();

   echo "<div><table class='demoTable'>";
   echo "<thead><tr>" .
   "<th>Username</th>" .
   "<th>Fullname</th>" .
   "<th>Email</th>" .
   "<th>Userlevel</th>" .
   "</tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    $allRows = $sth->fetchAll();
    foreach($allRows as $Row) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$Row['username']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Row['fullname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Row['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Row['userlevel']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table></div>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I am not getting anything back on the screen.  I just don't get it.

Comment: I just noticed that you had the </tbody> tag inside the loop. I edited my answer and placed it in the last echo. I think that probably stoped the table from displaying correctly

Comment: I made the update, but still nothing on screen.  I'm going to move the table headers outside of the PHP.

Comment: I tried recreating your code and it didn't run because the class name 'demoTable' in the table tag was in double paranthesis. So you should use single paranthesis. replace "demoTable" with 'demoTable'. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: I removed demoTable, but still nothing.  For some reason, using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) solved my problem.  I still don't get it though.